# Crack linux executable

Tags: linux, assembly, reverse-engineering, exploit

I have a linux executable and its disassembly (in particular, the program checks if I'm superuser, and if so, output some message by executing function "start_reactor" and exit; if I'm not a superuser the program call another function "check_password"), what I need is to find a way to crack it (execute function "start_reactor") by entering some specific string as an input for function "check_password".

Below is dissasembly of an executable..

```
08048504 <check_password>:
8048504:    55                   push   ebp
8048505:    89 e5                mov    ebp,esp
8048507:    b8 00 00 00 00       mov    eax,0x0
804850c:    5d                   pop    ebp
804850d:    c3                   ret    

0804850e <start_reactor>:
804850e:    55                   push   ebp
804850f:    89 e5                mov    ebp,esp
8048511:    83 ec 04             sub    esp,0x4
8048514:    c7 04 24 90 86 04 08 mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x8048690
804851b:    e8 0c ff ff ff       call   804842c <printf@plt>
8048520:    c7 04 24 2e 00 00 00 mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x2e
8048527:    e8 d0 fe ff ff       call   80483fc <putchar@plt>
804852c:    a1 60 98 04 08       mov    eax,ds:0x8049860
8048531:    89 04 24             mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
8048534:    e8 e3 fe ff ff       call   804841c <fflush@plt>
8048539:    c7 04 24 01 00 00 00 mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x1
8048540:    e8 07 ff ff ff       call   804844c <sleep@plt>
8048545:    eb d9                jmp    8048520 <start_reactor+0x12>

08048547 <main>:
8048547:    55                   push   ebp
8048548:    89 e5                mov    ebp,esp
804854a:    83 ec 1c             sub    esp,0x1c
804854d:    c7 45 f8 be ba fe ca mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8],0xcafebabe
8048554:    e8 e3 fe ff ff       call   804843c <getuid@plt>
8048559:    85 c0                test   eax,eax
804855b:    0f 94 c0             sete   al
804855e:    0f b6 c0             movzx  eax,al
8048561:    89 45 fc             mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],eax
8048564:    83 7d fc 00          cmp    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0x0
8048568:    75 24                jne    804858e <main+0x47>
804856a:    c7 04 24 b0 86 04 08 mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x80486b0
8048571:    e8 b6 fe ff ff       call   804842c <printf@plt>
8048576:    a1 60 98 04 08       mov    eax,ds:0x8049860
804857b:    89 04 24             mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
804857e:    e8 99 fe ff ff       call   804841c <fflush@plt>
8048583:    8d 45 e8             lea    eax,[ebp-0x18]
8048586:    89 04 24             mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
8048589:    e8 5e fe ff ff       call   80483ec <gets@plt>
804858e:    81 7d f8 be ba fe ca cmp    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8],0xcafebabe
8048595:    74 18                je     80485af <main+0x68>
8048597:    c7 04 24 d8 86 04 08 mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x80486d8
804859e:    e8 b9 fe ff ff       call   804845c <puts@plt>
80485a3:    c7 04 24 ff ff ff ff mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0xffffffff
80485aa:    e8 bd fe ff ff       call   804846c <exit@plt>
80485af:    83 7d fc 00          cmp    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0x0
80485b3:    75 0f                jne    80485c4 <main+0x7d>
80485b5:    8d 45 e8             lea    eax,[ebp-0x18]
80485b8:    89 04 24             mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
80485bb:    e8 44 ff ff ff       call   8048504 <check_password>
80485c0:    85 c0                test   eax,eax
80485c2:    74 05                je     80485c9 <main+0x82>
80485c4:    e8 45 ff ff ff       call   804850e <start_reactor>
80485c9:    c9                   leave  
80485ca:    c3                   ret    
80485cb:    90                   nop    
80485cc:    90                   nop    
80485cd:    90                   nop    
80485ce:    90                   nop    
80485cf:    90                   nop
```

..and result of a reverse ingeneering using IDA.

```
int __cdecl main()
{
  __uid_t v0; // eax@1
  int result; // eax@7
  char s; // [sp+4h] [bp-18h]@2
  int v3; // [sp+14h] [bp-8h]@1
  bool v4; // [sp+18h] [bp-4h]@1

  v3 = -889275714;
  v0 = getuid();
  v4 = v0 == 0;
  if ( v0 != 0 )
  {
    printf("Please enter the password to continue: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    gets(&s);
  }
  if ( v3 != -889275714 )
  {
    puts(" ");
    exit(-1);
  }
  if ( v4 || (result = check_password()) != 0 )
    start_reactor();
  return result;
}
```

I'm really new to Assembler.. :(

Comment: You probably mean `char s[16]` and `check_password(s)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a buffer overflow exploitation.

You have to overflow `s` to write over `v3` and `v4`.

This let me think that `s` is a `char s[16]` :

```
  char s; // [sp+4h] [bp-18h]@2  // 18h - 8h = 10h
  int v3; // [sp+14h] [bp-8h]@1
```

But in v3 you have to put in -889275714, so in hexadecimal 0xcafebabe (<3 it btw :D)

And then override the boolean with 0x01

so basically, you want to launch your binary with :

`perl -e 'print "junk_for_sssssss\xbe\xba\xfe\xca\x01"' | ./binary`

To be noted that you need to enter \xbe\xba\xfe\xca and not \xca\xfe\xba\xbe because of your potential little endian architecture

Comment: anxious to see the op return with "did not work" because of the typo in the copy&paste part of the answer. here is hoping it stays this way so that ppl at least have to understand what they are copying. `s` is not a `char s[10]` though, but a `char s[0x10]` (again, this might as well stay this way ;) )

Comment: @example Haha nice, didn't notice myself. I correct it. Thank's

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me you already know enough about the program. Run it using [fakeroot](http://man.he.net/man1/fakeroot) (and maybe a VM - depending on where you got this from). 
Not that `check_output` does nothing but return 0, so there is no way to convince it to execute `start_reactor` without rewriting the assembly or starting it as root or with fakeroot.

```
08048504 <check_password>:
8048504:    55                   push   ebp      // function header
8048505:    89 e5                mov    ebp,esp  // function header
8048507:    b8 00 00 00 00       mov    eax,0x0  // result = 0
804850c:    5d                   pop    ebp      // function footer
804850d:    c3                   ret             // return to callee
```

Of course if you want to modify the file (on disk or in memory) then there are a million ways to crack this (eg. change some jump so that it points to the `start_reactor` function is a standard approach). And you could always reverse the `start_reactor` function itself, as it is rather short - in which case I would advice you to look for the individual commands via google and try to understand what it does yourself...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, you are right, one possible way is to somehow emulate root and fakeroot is a good choice.. but according to what I know about the program, THERE IS a way to execute it just by entering specific string. For example, you see that it is aware of buffer overflow attacks (such check is present in the code), the solution is somehow connected with "canary value"...

Comment: yes, you are right, there actually is a string you can enter. seems it was posted before i could make the edit ^^